# On a recurrence relation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrences, tridiagonal-matrices

I am studying a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix $J_{N+1}$ (all off-diagonal elements non-zero) of dimension $N+1$, and I would like to solve the eigenvalue problem. The point is that the coefficients all depend on the dimension $N+1$, and change when N changes.

The on-diagonal elements are given by $a(i,N)=-\frac{1}{2N}(2i-N)^2$ where $(i=0,...,N)$, and the off-diagonal elements by $b(i,N)=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{((N-i+1)i)}$, where $i=1,...,N$.

If $v$ is an eigenvector, we can write $J_{N+1}v=\lambda_{N+1} v$, where $v=\sum_{i=0}^N\mu_ie_i$ for some coefficients $\mu_i$ and where $\{e_i\}_{i=0}^{N}$ is a basis. The number $\lambda_{N+1}$ (which depends on N) plays the role of an eigenvalue of the system.

One finds that the coefficients $\mu_i$ satisfy the following recurrence relation:

$\lambda_{N+1}\mu_i=b(i,N)\mu_{i+1}+a(i,N)\mu_i+b(i,N)\mu_{i-1}$,

where $\mu_0=1$ and $\mu_{-1}=0$.

I am particulary interested in the solution of this relation in the semiclassical regime where $N$ is large. Maybe things get more easy when N tends to infinity.
One possibility to start with is to multiply the matrix by $1/N$, so that the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are bounded. We find
$a(i,N)/N=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2i}{N}-1)^2$, and $b(i,N)/N=-1/2\sqrt{(1-i/N+1/N)(i/N)}$.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this recurrence relation? Thank you in advance!!